# MongoDb query funciona no shell, e não funciona no PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

Preciso de ajuda na consulta no banco de dados mongoDB, no shell posso executar a pesquisa normalmente, no entanto, no site, recebo o erro 'not authorized for query on'. Eu uso o serviço mLab para banco de dados.

Estou usando o mesmo usuário no shell e no PHP, a versão da minha database é 3.4.10 e a versão da biblioteca do codeigniter é 1.0.

Conexão com shell:

```
mongo ds249757.mlab.com:49757/tx5 -u user -p pass
```

Conexão codeigniter

```
<?php

//mongodb host
$config['default']['mongo_hostbase'] = 'ds249757.mlab.com:49757';
//mongodb name

$config['default']['mongo_database'] = 'tx5';
//mongodb username - by default, it is empty
$config['default']['mongo_username'] = 'user';
//mongodb password - by default, it is empty
$config['default']['mongo_password'] = 'pass';      
$config['default']['mongo_persist']  = FALSE;
$config['default']['mongo_persist_key']  = 'ci_persist';
$config['default']['mongo_replica_set']  = FALSE;
$config['default']['mongo_query_safety'] = 'safe';
$config['default']['mongo_suppress_connect_error'] = FALSE;
$config['default']['mongo_host_db_flag']   = FALSE; 

?>
```

Query no codeigniter

```
<?php 
        $this->load->library('mongo_db');
        $category = $this->mongo_db->db->admin->find();
       foreach ($category  as $cat)
       {
        $name=$cat['username'];
       $passwd=$cat['password'];
       }
         ?>
```

Telas

```html
<p>Permissões Usuário
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU7pY.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU7pY.png" alt="enter image description here"></a></p>

<p>Query no Shell
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgdyN.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgdyN.png" alt="enter image description here"></a></p>

<p>Query no codeigniter
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/43E4U.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/43E4U.png" alt="enter image description here"></a></p>

<p>Banco de dados MLAB
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEp3O.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEp3O.png" alt="enter image description here"></a></p>
```

Comment: Geralmente o mLab requere que se crie um usuário com permissao de leitura ou leitura e escrita na base de dados. Vc criou um? Mongo Shell está executando no mLab ou localhost?

Comment: Lucas o shell está executando no mLab também, o mesmo usuário e servidor configurado no shell foi configurado no php.

Comment: A mensagem é genérica Matheus, só diz que não está autorizado. Não sou especialista em codeigniter, mas sugiro que lá no mlab vc crie um usario (se ja nao fez) na guia usuarios. Dar permissao de leitura e escrita e testar com o usuario criado, usuario e senha. Perguntei na vdd se vc esta executando o shell dentro do mLab (no site). Pois por esta em dominio diferente poderia resultar em não autorizado

Comment: Lucas, quando tento criar um usuário `db.createUser( { user: "teste",
          pwd: "teste",
          roles: [ "readWriteAnyDatabase"

] } )` recebo o erro 'couldn't add user: No role named readWriteAnyDatabase'. Tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Esta criando pela interface do mLab mesmo? Cria direito pelo site..

Comment: Criei acontece o mesmo erro (Not authorized for query).

Comment: Ficou assim? https://imgur.com/a/Q1vRF

Comment: Sim, testei dessa forma e não foi, fiz um upgrade no usuário para readWrite e continuou não funcionando.

Comment: Então desculpa Matheus, provavel que seja algo especifico do codeigniter, talvez conflitos de versões ou parametro de configuração

Comment: É vou continuar checando o código aqui e ver se encontro algo.

Comment: Se ninguem aqui for mais assertivo, experimenta ir trocando os parametros, trocando versao da lib, testar por outra linguagem (java, node, etc), etc. boa sorte

Comment: Descobri na verdade o problema estava na biblioteca do codeigniter, ela não estava enviando o usuário e senha para conectar com o servidor.

Comment: Boa @MatheusArruda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema estava na biblioteca do codeigniter, ela não estava enviando o usuário e senha para conectar com o servidor.

Comment: gostaria de entender como voce resolver esse problema. é possivel?

Comment: @luismare qual biblioteca está usando? Está tentando fazer a conexão pelo code igniter mesmo? acho viável você abrir uma nova pergunta com os detalhes da sua dúvida, nesse caso deixe o link aqui que tento te ajudar lá.